# Representing multiple categories and dynamic visualization on a chart

Tags: data-visualization

I'm currently dealing with a heavy set of data, and I'd love to see a way to represent the variations between each set.

To give you a good idea of what I'm doing, I'm having a few methods that are creating certain links between entities (think it as edges between nodes if you want a graphical representation). The links are correct/incorrect.

Now, each method process the entities in steps. I have my data carefully annotated with (method, steps, correct/incorrect).

I'm trying to find a way to represent and filter data for visualization. My current idea is to use a dynamic drawing library (such as d3.js) to be able to regroup my entities spatially, filtered by category.

And I'd want to be able to "follow" a specific entity, so I can see what method/step is giving correct/incorrect to my data.

For example, if I were to use shape & colour as categories, I'd want to get something like
[image: My best try at paint]

I hope I'm posting in the right place. What pointers and help could you give me?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the pointers you are looking for? Are you asking if your software choice is appropriate? Or if your way of conceptualizing the problem is appropriate?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement : Both (conceptualization & software choice). I'm not used to this kind of representation.

Comment: I would just use arrows for each datum to connect its origin with its final position, and I would number each if I want to refer back to its numerical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but I thought it might help to think about the groupings separated spatially instead of over time. It makes the view more complicated but you can at least see the whole history. Here is something called *parallel sets* and you might find D3.js options by looking for "parallel coordinates" or "Sankey diagram."

[image]

This data is random, though I used the grouping names you mentioned. To help understand it, here's the same chart with one subset highlighted: those in both the grey and the circle groups. You can see about half of them go to correct and half of them go to incorrect. All the bands are colored by the number of correct elements and sized by the number of total elements.

[image]

Comment: Pretty much worked. :)